# Rails route file looks strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've just started working out of a rails 3 project in github and the routes.rb file doesn't seem to follow the usual format (eg: map.connect 'blahblahblah'). Instead it looks something like so:

```
MyProject::Application.routes.draw do

   root :to => 'content#index'

   match '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
   match '/login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login

  resources :accounts do
    resources :users


    member do
      post :upgrade
      get :cancel
    end
  end

  namespace :dashboard do
    resource :control_panel do
      member do
        post :show_info
      end
    end
  end
```

There a little more info after that but I've excluded it for brevitys sake. Can someone tell me how this file structure operates and specifically the difference between 'resource' and 'namespace' above?

Thanks,
  gearoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the rails 3 syntax for routing.  map.connect was the rails 2 syntax.

[Documentation for rails 3 routing.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Resource creates routes for the 7 CRUD actions in rails (Create, Index, Show, Update, Edit, New and Destroy.)  Namespace allows you to namespace the routes.

```
  namespace :dashboard do
    resource :control_panel do
      member do
        post :show_info
      end
    end
  end
```

This creates the 7 CRUD routes for control_panel under the dashboard namespace, such as:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/control_panel/new
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/control_panel/show/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Routing in Rails 3 got a pretty major overhaul.  Seems like you should probably read up on the new world order.  Check out the [Rails 3 Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).  It has a section on [Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and one on [Namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).